# dependencyManagement in parent ignored

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3

I have a project, P1, that creates a jar. That project has a parent POM, P1-PARENT. P1-Parent includes the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Kafka uses Zookeeper 3.3.4, but Curator requires 3.4.5. To resolve
         we specify 3.4.5 so all projects using either Kafka or Curator will
         get the later version which is compatible with both projects. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
      <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- A bunch of other irrelevant stuff here -->
</dependencyManagement>
```

This works - the output of "mvn dependency:tree" includes:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile (version managed from 3.3.4)
```

Note that this is the *only* dependency on zookeeper (verified via "mvn dependency:tree | grep zoo".

I have several other projects that also inherit from P1-PARENT and everything works fine, they all pull in ZooKeeper 3.4.5. However, A coworker of mine recently starting using P1 in one of their projects. Their project doesn't inherit from P1-PARENT. The transitive dependency they get from P1 is ZooKeeper 3.3.4, not 3.4.5. We have verified, via "mvn dependency:tree", that they get zookeeper.3.3.4 as a transitive dependency of Kafka (e.g. the output looks identical to what I've pasted above, but the version is 3.3.4 and it doesn't include the "(version managed ..." bit). Also, like my projects, the only dependency they have on ZooKeeper (transitive or otherwise) is through P1 (verified by dependency:tree and grep). The question is, *why*. When they include P1, shouldn't maven look at P1's parent POM when determining the transitive dependencies of P1?

I'm using Maven 3.0.5. They're using versions 3.0.3 and 3.1.1 and see the problem with both of those versions.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312975/maven-dependencymanagement-version-ignored-in-transitive-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Maven doesn't resolve the version transitive dependency issue in this case.

This issue can be used by using maven bom concept.

Check the maven documentation for bom in the below link
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Here is another blog which explains usage of bom's
http://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/

In your case to solve this issue, you need to add a dependency of your parent pom in the dependencyManagement section of other project where you are facing the issue.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; or at least, it doesn't seem very useful. The point of dependencyManagement is to allow_me_to_specify_a_version for transitive dependencies, not inherit the version of another project

Answer (score 0):

When using Maven3, ensure you're using the right version of the `maven-dependency-plugin` by calling it by its fully qualified name: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree`. IIRC up to 2.6 gave a wrong tree. In such cases the advice was: run your project as 'mvn validate -X' to see the tree as resolved by Aether, the dependency management framework for Maven.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does the dependency plugin specification have to go in any project using P1, in P1-PARENT, or in P1 itself?

Comment: I would include the maven-dependency-plugin 2.8 in the pluginManagement of the most upper parent, so you can use `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Thanks. The other team has left for the day so I can't test this yet. Will test tomorrow and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Hitting the same problem with maven 3.2.3. Also set up a small example project reproducing the described situation. Using maven-dependency-plugin 2.8 did not change anything. Also verified that this is not only a problem of `dependency:tree` but the wrong version of the transitive dependency ends up in the final artifact (e. g. war). Anybody else has ideas about this?