# Maven dependencyManagement version ignored in transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3

Maven is transitively pulling in version 16 of guava, even though I have a <dependencyManagement> section which specifies version 18.

The quick summary:

- `gwizard-example` depends on `gwizard-config`
- `gwizard-config` has a parent pom, `gwizard-parent`
- `gwizard-parent` has <dependencyManagement> which specifies version 18 of guava

Thankfully this is an opensource project, so you can see the poms directly: [gwizard-parent](https://github.com/gwizard/gwizard/blob/master/pom.xml), [gwizard-config](https://github.com/gwizard/gwizard/blob/master/gwizard-config/pom.xml), [gwizard-example](https://github.com/gwizard/gwizard-example/blob/master/pom.xml). However, here's the important bit in `gwizard-parent`:

```
<properties>
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

...and the no-frills dependency declared in gwizard-example:

```
<properties>
    <gwizard.version>0.5</gwizard.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwizard-config</artifactId>
        <version>${gwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The dependency tree for gwizard-config shows guava 18 correctly:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ gwizard-config ---
[INFO] org.gwizard:gwizard-config:jar:0.5
[INFO] +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0-beta5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
```

However, the dependency tree for gwizard-example shows guava 16 (which causes problems):

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ gwizard-example ---
[INFO] org.gwizard:gwizard-example:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.gwizard:gwizard-config:jar:0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0-beta5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
```

This is using Maven v3.2.5. I am baffled. Help?

Possibly related: [dependencyManagement in parent ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846181/dependencymanagement-in-parent-ignored)

**UPDATE**: The poms linked on github are changing; adding a dependency to `gwizard-services` (which directly declares a guava dep) in `gwizard-example` "fixed" the problem. There's still some sort of bad underlying behavior here.

**UPDATE**: Created [this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5761)

Comment: It looks like your issue is approaching resolution - maybe someone can soon post an answer which starts with "just use Maven 4"!

Answer (score 14):

There is a simple thing. A `dependencyManagement` does not declare a dependency which is **really used** it's only defining versions etc. which **can** be used.

If you define something like this it will not result in a change.

```xml
<properties>
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If you really like to overwrite the version which is used in you tree you need to define a real dependency:
So based on the above definition you need to add the following as well:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you have added this please check afterwards via `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; or at least, it doesn't seem very useful. The point of `dependencyManagement` is to allow me to specify a version for transitive dependencies. Here, guava is being pulled in transitively via guice. Why doesn't my `dependencyManagement` control the version pulled in by guice? Why should I specify guava as a dependency if my library does not directly depend on guava?

Comment: The simple answer to this is, cause the maintainer of the pom of guice have decided to use an other version. So you can't directly control the pom which is used there. You can only control it indirectly.  BTW: `dependencyManagement` does not control. `dependencies` does instead, cause it's nearer to your project.

Comment: @khmarbaise Does this mean that if example had defined a dependencyManagement section with guava 18, it would still pull of guava:16 from gwizard-config, or did I understood it incorrectly?
That is the shocking part, not the fact that transitive's parent dependencyManagement is ignored. Because, then, dependencyManagement would be completely useless for managing transitive dependencies versions

Comment: Nope, I just tested it with these particular dependencies and it does work as expected, not as stated. If you place the first code section you suggest, then guava 18 is pulled off transitively from config dependence into example. You don't need to declare the transitive dependency (guava) as you state in the second part, for the depencencymanagement section to have effect (even if that guava version was unrefered on transitive dependencies, it will take 18)

Comment: @Whimusical you are correct. as a matter of fact I think we just had to fix kind of the opposite of the issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/849). We override a version, which causes a slight miss-understanding. imo both the answer and the question are not up to date anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't resolve the version transitive dependency issue in this case.

This issue can be used by using maven `bom` concept.

Check the [Maven documentation for `bom`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).

[Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/) is another blog which explains usage of a `bom`.

In your case to solve this issue, you need to add the below dependency in the `dependencyManagement` section of the project `gwizard-example`.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.gwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwizard-parent</artifactId>
  <version>${gwizard.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense; or at least, it doesn't seem very useful. The point of dependencyManagement is to _allow_me_to_specify_a_version_ for transitive dependencies, not inherit the version of another project ...

Comment: I tried import parent as you suggested, but it didn't work for me. I still see incorrect library version.