# dependency management, transitive dependencies and copy-dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to force a specific version of a transitive dependency in my project. This is accomplished by declaring the transitive dependency with the specific version in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the pom.
When I run dependency:tree on the project the correct/forced version of the transitive dependency is printed.

The "problem" is when I use the dependency plugin with goal copy-dependencies to copy all the project dependencies and transitive dependencies to a specific location, I still get the old version of the transitive dependency, not the version specified in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.
Why is that and what is best practise to handle this scenario?

Comment: What do you get when you call `mvn dependency:list` ?

Comment: Then I get the version specified in <depenendencyManagement> section.

Comment: Are you sure you cleaned previous copy attempts?

Comment: Thank you but I think I didn't really understand how Maven works in this case https://stackoverflow.com/q/28312975/964592. According to that answer Maven ignores versions of dependencies declared only in the <dependendyManagement> section for transitive dependencies. I agree with the OP of that question, that it's quite unexpected